# Obter um atributo específico do HTML utilizando Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Estou tentando capturar (pegar) um atributo chamado `srcset` dentro de um tag `img`

```
<img _ngcontent-games2-c5="" class="mdc-image-list__image ng-lazyloaded" offset="100" src="/assets/img/lazy-load.jpg" srcset="https://juegosv.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/powerline-io.jpg" alt="Powerline.io">
```

O meu código escrito em Python é o seguinte:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = get("http://jogos.io").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html5lib")

uls = soup.find("ul", {
    "class": "mdc-image-list"
})


imgs = uls.findAll("img")

print(f"{imgs}\n")
```

Ele me retorna uma lista com vários tags de imagens:

```
[<img _ngcontent-sc7="" alt="Powerline.io" class="mdc-image-list__image" offset="100" src="/assets/img/lazy-load.jpg"/>, <img _ngcontent-sc7="" alt="tacticscore.io" class="mdc-image-list__image" offset="100" src="/assets/img/lazy-load.jpg"/>, ...]
```

Mas o atributo `srcset` não aparece em nenhuma delas. Só consigo ver esse atributo se eu *inspecionar elemento* dentro do site através do navegador.

Perguntas:
Tem como fazer isso?
O que preciso fazer?

Comment: Talvez seja preciso aguardar a execução de algum script javascript, utilizando o `selenium` provavelmente irá resolver. Mas qual é o objetivo? fazer o download das imagens?

Comment: Na verdade o objetivo é aprendizado, cara. Estou vendo tutoriais na internet sobre *Django*, aí eu tive a ideia de fazer um site que "pegue" as informações de outros sites e exiba no meu sem eu ter que fazer download de nada, entendeu? A fim de aprendizado apenas.

Comment: Realmente analisei um arquivo Javascript e vi que a partir lá ele insere esse `srcset` no `HTML`. Eu consigo utilizar o **Selenium** pra isso? Eu só conheço o *Selenium* pra fazer automações.

Comment: Teoricamente deve funcionar com o selenium já que ele "simula" um browser, mas na real precisaria testar porque com o javascript as coisas ficam meio imprevisíveis. Mas seria apenas substituir o requests pelo selenium.